# Testing Moment in React Enzyme Jest

Tags: javascript, reactjs, momentjs, formik

I am Using React, Formick and material UI

The UI functionality is working fine, I need to write test case for Formik handle Submit.
so I wrote the formk test case as usual, but not what is happening is i am using picker and i am getting date in `Friday, February 5, 2016 at 9:00:00 pm UTC`  to convert i am using Moment and i am able to verify it in UI and is working fine but as soon as i try to test the same
it says moment is not a function. what i am doing wrong? I want to use moment only for conversion as it is being used in my application need a way to test it in jest ezyme

https://codesandbox.io/s/competent-thompson-s075hi?file=/src/app.test.js

Comment: Relevant: https://github.com/moment/moment/issues/5166

Comment: No I tried this but its not working